# Is it a right way to create a content sharing/commenting website?

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

I'm not an experienced web developer so please don't judge me if the question will sound stupid but actually I have no idea how to accomplish my task.

Basically, I want to create a simple website where an user can upload his picture ant receive comments/feedback from people he shares the picture with.

I'm curious, would it be OK to build a complex link (of a page with a picture) that the user could share with others and the visitors could comment on it?

It sounds like a good solution for me but I'm not competent enough to distinguish if it's a good practice.

Moreover, could I assure that other people (who don't have a link) do not get into the page with the picture?

I think of using Joomla CMS, a custom article template (for displaying pictures + comments) and some extension to produce a complex link.

Please share your thoughts about this. I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. Thank you.

Comment: Too broad. Please narrow your question down to a specific programming related issue.

Comment: Well if you're using Joomla there are tons of extensions. You just need to find one that suits you. For example take a look at [JomSocial](http://www.jomsocial.com). At most you will have to create your own template.

Comment: Well, mainly I'm asking if sharing a link to the specific page is safe and others (who don't have a link) won't be able to open that page. Thank you for a recommendation, though I don't want to create a social network, I just want something like [Dribbble](http://www.dribbble.com). The only difference would be that you can't explore all projects, you can see only the one you have a link to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try BT Galley of Bowthemes. They just made a image-video management component called BT Media and this is built in BT Gallery template.

The link http://bowthemes.com/joomla-templates/bt-gallery.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want only share picture on site with users and comment system then you can use wordpress CMS.

1. Once you installed wordpress then you can search wordpress templates as per your requirement ( search on google "free wordpress template for images").
2. Install template and start adding content.
3. If you want to share that content with social networks like facebook, twitter, then wordpress provide plugin for that. We just need to install that plugins.

I hope I cover all your answers.

Let me know if you have anything queries.